# How can I call a Linq-to-Entities (EF4) query specifying a different table name dynamically?

Tags: linq, dynamic, entity-framework-4

I have a bunch of tables that all have a field called `ResourceID` that are populated from an outside process. I want to go through each table and validate that ID against a master list. The code is simple but gets repetitive:

```
var resList = (from r in dc.ResourceMasterEntities select r.ResourceId).ToList();
var res = (from rs in resList select (int?)rs).ToList();

    var stage = (from s in dc.TableOne select s.ResourceId).ToList();
    foreach (var invalidResourceID in stage.Except(res).ToList())
    {
        errList.Add("Bad ID found:" + invalidResourceID );
    }

    stage = (from s in dc.TableTwo select s.ResourceId).ToList();
    foreach (var invalidResourceID in stage.Except(res).ToList())
    {
        errList.Add("Bad ID found:" + invalidResourceID );
    }

    // more of the same with different tables
```

I would like to create a function where I can pass in the name of the table (`TableOne`, `TableTwo`, etc) and not have to write all of this repetitive code. Can this be done with Linq? (and preferably not using `ExecuteQuery` :-))

Comment: Are you using/talking about **Linq-to-SQL** or about **Entity Framework** - pick one!

Comment: It's EF but in this context does it matter?  It is linq going against a SQL database.  If I am wrong, please set me straight.

Comment: **Linq-to-SQL** is a separate OR mapper - it was written by the C# team, more or less as a "proof of concept" for what LINQ could do. EF supports LINQ - called Linq-to-Entities. So Linq-to-SQL and EF are two separate, closely related things - but they're different products / different bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function that takes an IQueryable as a parameter.

The function would look like:

```
  private void CheckTable(IQueryable<EntityType> table)
  {
      var stage = (from s in table select s.ResourceId).ToList();
      foreach (var invalidResourceID in stage.Except(res).ToList())
      {
          errList.Add("Bad ID found:" + invalidResourceID);
      }
  }

  // Execute the function like:
  CheckTable(dc.TableOne);
```

You can choose if you make errList and res class level properties or if you pas them as parameters to the function

Comment: This is a good answer but I get an error on s.ResourceID because there is no such property on EntityType - any idea how to get around this?

Comment: EntityType was just a placeholder for the entity type you are using. In your code you did a (from s in dc.TableOne select s.ResourceId) so I used that select statement. How are you calling the function?

Answer (score 0):

With some modification I was able to get this to work - I had to use the built in dynamic linq to select the property that I wanted.

```
private void CheckTable(System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<EntityType> table)   
{
        var records = table.Select("BusinessEntityNbr").ToList();
        var values = (from r in records select (int?)r[0]).ToList();

        foreach (var invalidResourceID in values.Except(res).ToList())       
        {
           errList.Add("Bad ID found:" + invalidResourceID);       
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using entity SQL and DbDataRecord for unknown result types. See the Entity SQL samples in http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFQuerySamples for some ideas on how to use Entity SQL.